# page redirect in wordpress with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

hey i am new in wordpress here i want to redirect my page to another page.
right now 
http://www.mysite.com/page is working and what i need to do is 
http://www.mysite.com/page/page1 on this link again i want to display the same page (http://www.mysite.com/page)
for the above i have changed my .htaccess file like shown below

```
RewriteRule ^page/page1(.*)$ /page [L]
RewriteRule ^page/page1  /page [L]
RewriteRule ^page/page1  /page[L]
```

can you help me get out of this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Googling for ["wordpress .htaccess"](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+.htaccess) yields over 2.2 *million* results.

Answer (score 0):

hello i will suggest you to use this plugin :- 
http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Answer (score 0):

Just install this plugin you will find a text box on the bottom of every page in `PAGES` section where you can put your desired link/URL.

[Page link to pluggin][1]